# Freedb / Asunder : Unknown Host Name

Tags: cd-ripping, cddb

I just downloaded Asunder and ran it and get an Unknown Host Name error which apparently is because [freedb is no longer a thing](https://www.gusnan.se/blog/programming/freedb-is-closing-its-service/). That was 9 months ago. Why was Asunder still try to access freedb and what can be used in its place?

```
~$ sudo apt install asunder
[sudo] password for zzz:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
asunder is already the newest version (2.9.5-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very latest version of Asunder does *not* in fact use freedb, having successfully moved the default cddb lookup to gnudb. Older versions of Asunder (versions before 2.9.6) can be brought back to life by changing the relevant settings under:

```
Preferences --> Advanced --> CDDB
```

Alter your settings in this location to match the following:

[image]

And then all should be well...

Comment: Thanks, gnudb works for me. I added version information for Asunder to the original question. It says I have the newest version.

Comment: @AlLelopath Good to hear it has all worked out! The package manager is telling you that you have the most modern version available in the repository rather than the newest version available upstream. The CDDB settings were actually changed in version 2.9.6 and the latest version is 2.9.7.